# WPF DataContext Binding & DataContextChanged Event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, wpf-controls

I am having issues with the DataContextChanged event not firing as expected.

In my Main Window XAML I have a User Control declared as so:

```
<UserControls:PeopleView DataContext="{Binding People}"></UserControls:PeopleView>
```

In my Main Window CodeBehind I have the 'People' datasource declared as so:

```
Public Property People() As PersonCollection
    Get
        Return _People
    End Get
    Set(value As PersonCollection)
        _People = value
        UpdateProperty("People")
    End Set
End Property
```

In my PeopleView user control I have the following:

```
Public Sub OnDataContextChanged() Handles Me.DataContextChanged

    Console.WriteLine("Data context changed")

End Sub
```

When the Main Window is initially rendered, and the PeopleView DataContext is bound to the 'People' property for the first time, the event fires as expected. However, when I subsequently change the 'People' property to a different collection from within Main Window, the DataContextChanged event is not firing:

```
Me.People = New PeopleCollection
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface with the `DataContextChanged` event. It's the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface that would notify of a change to a property like your `People` property, not the `DataContextChanged` event... note that this changes the value of the `People` property and is *not* setting the `DataContext`:

```
Me.People = New PeopleCollection
```

*This* is changing the `DataContext` property:

```
DataContext = New PeopleCollection
```

Comment: I am changing the PeopleCollection in the Main Window. I am assuming that I want this to fire the INotifyPropertyChanged event on the People property, which will then update the DataContext binding for PeopleView in the XAML, which will then fire the DataContextChanged event in the PeopleView user control?

Comment: You are assuming incorrectly. However, it is a rare situation when the `DataContextChanged` event is actually required to be handled, so I think that you shouldn't be using it in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure that your answer is a solution. How do I change the DataContext of the PeopleView control through databinding then? If I have DataContext="{Binding People}" then I should be able to update the People property and have the DataContext change. This is not happening, despite raising the PropertyChanged event on 'People'

Comment: You said *I am having issues with the DataContextChanged event not firing as expected*... I explained why. So of course I didn't answer the question that you have only just asked now: *How do I change the DataContext of the PeopleView control through databinding then?* The only question that you actually asked initially was *What am I doing wrong?*. You can't change your question and expect that an answer provided *before* you changed it would answer it.

Comment: Normally, we *don't* change the `DataContext` like you are attempting. We set it to an instance of a class that contains *all* of the data and functionality required for a view. If anything needs to be updated, we update the properties inside the class and make sure to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: Fair enough re clarity of original question. So you are saying that DataContext="{Binding People}" and updating the People property using INotify does not, and will never work, the same way as Content="{Binding FirstName}" and updating the FirstName property using INotify?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was binding the DataContext of a UserControl to a property Wizard. I had wizards that derived from DependencyObject and DataContextChanged fired fine. Then I switched to retrieving the next wizard using an interface, and DataContextChanged stopped firing. Every wizard derived from WizardBase, which derived from DependencyObject, but since DataContext saw something, the interface, that was not derived from DependencyObject it ignored the change. When I converted the interface to WizardBase everything worked fine. So could the problem be the PeopleCollection.